# Can't run MVVMcros Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I'm trying to configure MVVMCrosswith Xamarin.Forms. So I'm creating XF project, adding antoher PCL project for viewmodels. Next I'm instaling needed MVVMCross nugets includng Mvvmcross.StarterPack, MVVMCross.Forms and MVVMCross.Presentation. Then I'm cleaning in project from auto created trash ets. To this moment everything building. But when I change in XF MainPage.xaml ContentPage to MvxContentPage in building time there is following error:

```
    The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'StormFinder, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'StormFinder.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.GetAssembly(String fileName)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res, ICollection`1 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() StormFinder.Android
```

StormFinder is my XF UI project. I've tried everything,   including  cleaning, reinstalling XF, MVVMCross or even starting new project.

What can I do?
EDIT:
Project can be found there: https://github.com/straiser/StormFinder

EDIT2:
It was wrong namespace in xaml. Project is building now, but now I have got another error:

```
 System.TypeLoadException: Parent class vtable failed to initialize, due to: Type MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.Core.MvxFormsPagePresenter has invalid vtable method slot 7 with method MvvmCross.Core.Views.MvxViewPresenter:Close (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxViewModel) assembly:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/StormFinder.Android/files/.__override__/MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.Core.dll type:MvxFormsPagePresenter member:<none>
06-12 18:52:19.744 E/mono-rt ( 1784): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Parent class vtable failed to initialize, due to: Type MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.Core.MvxFormsPagePresenter has invalid vtable method slot 7 with method MvvmCross.Core.Views.MvxViewPresenter:Close (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxViewModel) assembly:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/StormFinder.Android/files/.__override__/MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.Core.dll type:MvxFormsPagePresenter member:<none>
```

Comment: Your XF UI project is a PCL? Or Shared? Have you referenced it from your Platform project? If you can, upload a sample project. It will help narrowing down the issue.

Comment: @woelliJ My XF is PCL and it's refrenced. I pushed project to github. Link is in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the namespace of the `MvxContentPage` in your `MainPage`.

It needs to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<core1:MvxContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StormFinder"
              xmlns:core="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.Core;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.Core"
              xmlns:core1="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Core;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
              x:Class="StormFinder.MainPage">

    <Label Text="{Binding Text}" 
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <!-- core:MvxContentPage -->
</core1:MvxContentPage>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's building now, but look on EDIT2 in my post.

Comment: Ok, doesn't matter. I fixed this. Thanks for help.